# VBA script to replace cell value and keep formatting

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have the below table in word that I'm trying to write a script to replace the contents of the below cell with a different customer payment (i.e replace the £1,100 with £2,000). Below is a snippet of my script but the when I write back to the cell it loses all the formatting and the numbered list.

**How can I keep replace the cell data with very similar data and still keep the formatting?**

ps. I've simplified the contents of the cell to make it easier to read, so the code won't apply to exactly that content

[image: Before]
[image: After]

```
DescPlan = Trim(t1.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text)
DescTest = InStr(1, DescPlan, ":")
finalString = Left(DescPlan, DescTest)

t1.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = Replace(DescPlan, finalString, "Payment by the customer of " + Format(v, "Currency") + " will be due upon completion of items below:")
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the whole thing, why not just replace the value of the currency amount?

Comment: How is this related to Microsoft Word? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @dwirony how would I go about doing that? Because you couldn't do replace as the value of £1,100 could be different in every row of the table I apply this to.

Comment: @BrunoBieri the table exists in ms-word plus the vba script I'm writing applies to a word document.

Comment: If you manipulate some ranges and store the value of £1,100 in a variable, you can do a Replace of the whole line similar to your example above: `"Payment by the customer of " & mynumber & " will be due upon completition of the items below:"` I believe that by doing a Replace instead of rewriting to the cell, the format should hold...

Comment: You could use a field called "DocProperty" and just replace the value within this field. The field will automatically present the new value. Look for custom document properties.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you are using a table so what works for excel should also work for you.

```
Sub replace_keep_format()

Dim t1 As Range
Dim sStrng As String, rStrng As String
Dim i As Integer

sStrng = "£1,100"
rStrng = "£2,000"
i = 1

Do Until ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a" & i) = ""
Set t1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("a" & i)
t1 = Replace(Expression:=t1, Find:=sStrng, Replace:=rStrng)
i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```